# Reading BLOB data from an Esri GDB with OGR

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr

Is it possible to read a binary data field (BLOB) from an Esri geodatabase using OGR? I'm using the OpenFileGDB driver and can extract the first few bytes, but then it truncates the data with "...".

```
>>> import ogr
>>> src = ogr.Open("data.gdb")
>>> src.GetDriver().name
'OpenFileGDB'
>>> layer = src.GetLayerByName("Photo__ATTACH")
>>> feature = layer.GetFeature(1)
>>> data = feature.GetField("DATA")
>>> len(data)
75
>>> data
'FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100004800480000FFE100584578696600004D4D002A0000...'
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the driver, or if I just need to pass it a particular flag?

`FFD8` is the start of a JPEG file in HEX.

The equivalent in ArcGIS-speak is here: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011912

Comment: OGR data model seems to support Raw Binary Data http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a787194bea637faf12d61643124a7c9fc so it should be possible to support BLOBs. I would write to gdal-dev mailing list and ask.

Comment: Can't test myself right now, but maybe you could test write the Python bytes (if this is what you get) into a jpeg file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748549/python-file-i-o-with-binary-data

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov The issue is that the BLOB is truncated. I only get the first 72 hex characters, while the image should be a few megabytes of data.

Comment: There seems to be a "GetFieldAsBinary" function, but I don't have it in my install? https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py#L3430

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After upgrading to a more recent version of GDAL (was using 1.11.4, now on 2.1.1) the feature object provides a `GetFieldAsBinary` method. This returns the full data as a bytes object.

```
>>> data = feature.GetFieldAsBinary("DATA")
>>> len(data)
2735908
```

Comment: Ah, this is very useful, didn't know there is support for this in gdal, very cool. Do you get Python bytes you can write with `wb` option to file?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.